# Asyncio task running synchrounous

Tags: python-3.x, http, async-await, python-asyncio

I am new to python and trying to do http post request in parallel to speed up the process time for script

The script fetches data from Excel sheet wise and execute http post for each row in sheet. Below is the code that I am trying:

```
def auth():
    "Do something"

def read_excel():
    xlfile='data.xls'
    xls=pandas.ExcelFile(xlfile)
    df1=pandas.read_excel(xls,'sheet1')
    df2=pandas.read_excel(xls,'sheet2')
    return df1,df2

def trigger_job(auth_user,headers,url,record):
    payload=request.post(url,auth=(auth_user,auth_pass),headers,record)
    '''some code to further process data'''

def template_read(sheet):
    with open('templates.json') as templates:
        data=json.load(templates)
    url=data[sheet]['url']
    return url

async def execute_job(df,url,auth_user,auth_pass,headers):
    yeslist=["yes","YES"]
    recycledf=df[df['Recycle?'].isin(yeslist)]
    recycledf=recycledf.drop(['Recycle?'],axis=1)
    recycle_json=recycledf.to_json(orient='records')
    for record in recycle_json:
        trigger_job(auth_user,headers,url,record)

async def main():
    sheet1=loop.create_task(execute_job(df1,template_read("sheet1"),auth_user,auth_pass,headers)
    sheet2=loop.create_task(execute_job(df2,template_read("sheet2"),auth_user,auth_pass,headers)
    await asyncio.wait([sheet1,sheet2])

if __name__=="__main__":
    auth_user,auth_pass,headers=auth()
    df1,df2=read_excel()
    loop= asyncio.geteventloop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This code runs the sheet1 and sheet2 task in synchrounous. Sheet1 task execute_job and the for loop blocks the sheet2 task

While my expectation is is to run sheet1 task and sheet2 two task in parallel and collect the result in end.

As I am new to learning, any lead would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: In order for your code to run asynchronously it needs to await something that yields back to the event loop. If you’re trying to run blocking code asynchronously, take a look at multiprocessing.

Comment: I tried await.sleep(1) post trigger_job() function. But it's still runs in series

Comment: Did you put the await inside the for loop or after it? How do you know that the code is running serially? Either way, though, if you aren't working with asyncio-aware libraries, there is no real value in using asyncio over something like `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Your tasks are not async. No amount of wrapping them in coroutines will make them async – in the end, all significant work will still be synchronous.